# ParseError: /node_modules/preact/compat/dist/compat.module.js/jsx-runtime.js

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, parse-error, preact

Error:

```
ParseError: /node_modules/preact/compat/dist/compat.module.js/jsx-runtime.js
Error: ENOTDIR: not a directory, open 'node_modules/preact/compat/dist/compat.module.js/jsx-runtime.js'
```

**Issue:** When I tried to migrate my react app from react-bootstrap v1 to react-bootstrap v2, I am getting the above error.

**root cause:** I guess the reason could be because of the aliasing method I use in the rollup.config.js file below. My objective in the below code is to alias react to preact which is working fine till react-bootstrap 1.6.4 but the error arises when I try to update/migrate the existing react-bootstrap 1.6.4 to it's latest version 2.2.3

Code:

``  alias({

entries: [

```
 ...['react', 'react-dom'].map(find => (
    { find, replacement: path.resolve(__dirname,'./node_modules/preact/compat/dist/compat.module.js') }
     ))
    ]
}), ``
```

**Workaround:** tried many workarounds for aliasing react to preact(rollup, webpack etc., from the official documentation provided in preact, but nothing seems to be working. The current preact version I am using is 10.x

**My query:** Is there a way to resolve this issue? I didn't make any code changes during the migration but the existing rollup config aliasing is breaking. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You're aliasing incorrectly. The newer version of `react-boostrap` must use the new(-er) JSX runtime, and your alias is creating a junk path.

Take the following:

```js
import { jsx } from 'react/jsx-runtime';
```

Your alias sees "react", and converts it to your alias:

```js
import { jsx } from './node_modules/preact/compat/dist/compat.module.js/jsx-runtime';
```

Which is clearly not right.

You want to use the alias listed on our docs site:

```js
import alias from '@rollup/plugin-alias';

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    alias({
      entries: [
        { find: 'react', replacement: 'preact/compat' },
        { find: 'react-dom/test-utils', replacement: 'preact/test-utils' },
        { find: 'react-dom', replacement: 'preact/compat' },
        { find: 'react/jsx-runtime', replacement: 'preact/jsx-runtime' }
      ]
    })
  ]
};
```

Comment: Woo-hoh, yess. I tried the workound and it’s migrated now. Thanks ton!

Comment: It's not a workaround, just the proper solution [copy/pasted from the docs](https://preactjs.com/guide/v10/getting-started#aliasing-in-rollup). Glad this helped though, make sure to mark it as the answer so others know it solved your issue.